# Error when creating a custom page in Drupal 7

Tags: php, function, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

(Using Adaptive Theme) I want a new and custom user login page. So, put this code in my template.php:

```
function mythemename_theme() {
  $items = array();
  // create custom user-login.tpl.php
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'user-login',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
  'mythemename_preprocess_user_login'
  ),
 );
return $items;
}
```

Changed mythemename to my custom theme name. And created user-login.tpl.php files and put this code:

```
<?php 
  print drupal_render($form['name']);
  print drupal_render($form['pass']);
  print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
  print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
  print drupal_render($form['actions']);
?>
```

Lastly, cleared my site cache. But when i click mysite.com/user login page not changed.

Where the error am I doing? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: use name user--login.tpl.php instead of user-login.tpl.php bcoz in drupal 7 use double -- instead of 1

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions. Pick one site that is best matched. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65475/error-when-creating-a-custom-page-in-d7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in template.php, change *mythemename* to theme name, and flush the cache.

```
function mythemename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    $hooks['user_login']=array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'template'=>'templates/user-login',
    );
    return $hooks;
}
```

Then in templates/user-login.tpl.php insert:

```
<?php
print render($form['name']);
print render($form['pass']);
print render($form['form_build_id']);
print render($form['form_id']);
print render($form['actions']);
?>
```

or

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
```